# [xAct][xCoba] Derive Metric Related Quantities like Riemann/Ricci Tensor/Scalar, Det(g), Christoffel Symbols

Tags: xact, field-theory

I'd like to prepare a mathematica notebook, where I can define a metric and derive quantities like the Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor, the Ricci scalar, the determinant of the metric and the various Christoffel symbols based on that metric.

Since I'd like to express everything in the coordinates I chose when defining the metric, I thought using xCoba within xAct would be optimal.

It's been a couple of years since I last used xAct and I mostly worked with xPand. My most recent attempt with xCoba wasn't too fruitful, but I am happy to share my attempt:

```
<< xAct`xCoba`
$DefInfoQ = False;
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
DefManifold[M, 2, IndexRange[a, n]]
DefChart[cart, M, {0, 1}, {x[], y[]}]
DefScalarFunction[\[Omega]]
MatrixForm[
 MatrixMetric = Exp[2 \[Omega][x[], y[]]]/2 {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]
met = CTensor[MatrixMetric, {-cart, -cart}]
MetricCompute[met, cart, All]
SetCMetric[met, cart, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
CD = CovDOfMetric[met];
RicciScalar[CD][]
Ricci[CD]
Riemann[CD]
ChristoffelFromMetric[met[-a, -b], cart][c, d, e]
Determinant[met]
```

What am I missing / doing wrong here, to get the correct results properly displayed? In the end, I would like to be able to just change the dimension of the manifold, define my coordinates in the chart, and plugin my metric and get everything else.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: *the Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor, the Ricci scalar, the determinant of the metric and the various Christoffel symbols* You could calculate all of these things with a few lines of your own code. None of the formulas are particularly complicated.